# Establecer valor de columna en dataframe en base a una condición

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un data frame cuya columna llamada *ModifiedDate* la quiero comparar con otra variable que es la fecha actual menos 60 días, y hacer esto en un bucle `for`.

Lo que busco es que si la fecha en *ModifiedDate* es mayor o igual a 60 días atrás del día de hoy, se le establezca la condición de *Open* dentro de la columna *Status*, en caso contrario se le establezca *Closed*.

```
rango = today - timedelta(days = 60)
rango = rango.strftime(format = ("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") )

for i in range(1,len(df)):
    if df.loc[i,"ModifiedDate"] >= rango:
        df.loc[i,"Status"] = ("Open")
    else:
         df.loc[i,"Status"] = ("Closed")
```

El problema es que los resultados que me aparecen son *Open* para las fechas del mismo año y *Closed* para las fechas de años anteriores.

Comment: ceo que la condicion esta mal no deberias evaluar `>= rango` ya que evaluara **TODO** lo que sea mayor al rango de 60, mas no que este en un rango de `hoy +60` y lo mismo para el else; evalua **TODO** lo menor a 60 dias, mas no que este en el rango de `hoy-60`. de lo contrario tomara todo lo anterior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El siguiente código es solo un ejemplo de la importación de los datos, se cargan en un DataFrame llamado *df*.

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

fechas = ['2021-5-1 10:00:00', '2021-4-1 09:00:00', '2021-3-1 08:00:00', '2021-2-1 07:00:00', '2021-1-1 06:00:00', '2020-12-1 05:00:00', '2020-11-1 04:00:00', '2020-10-1 03:00:00', '2020-9-1 02:00:00', '2020-8-1 01:00:00']

df = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(fechas, name='ModifiedDate'), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').to_frame()

print("Fecha hoy:  {}".format(dt.datetime.now()))

rango = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days = 60)
```

La siguiente linea, realiza todo el trabajo.

```
df['Status'] = np.where(df['ModifiedDate']<=rango, 'Closed', 'Open')
```

**El código completo, seria:**

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

fechas = ['2021-5-1 10:00:00', '2021-4-1 09:00:00', '2021-3-1 08:00:00', '2021-2-1 07:00:00', '2021-1-1 06:00:00', '2020-12-1 05:00:00', '2020-11-1 04:00:00', '2020-10-1 03:00:00', '2020-9-1 02:00:00', '2020-8-1 01:00:00']
df = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(fechas, name='ModifiedDate'), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').to_frame()

print("Fecha hoy:  {}".format(dt.datetime.now()))

rango = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days = 60)

# La eficacia de numpy y pandas, en una linea y sin tantos for e if
df['Status'] = np.where(df['ModifiedDate']<=rango, 'Closed', 'Open')

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Como dije en mi comentario, la condicion esta mal, ya que esta evalua **TODO** lo que este antes del día de hoy, incluyendo lo que esta hace 61, 69, 100 días; por consiguiente el `else` evalua lo contrario. dicho esto ahora se puede implementar la solucion correcta.

```py
hoy = today
rango = today - timedelta(days = 60)
rango = rango.strftime(format = ("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") )

for i in range(1,len(df)):
    if df.loc[i,"ModifiedDate"] in range(rango, hoy):
        df.loc[i,"Status"] = ("Open")
    elif df.loc[i,"ModifiedDate"] in range(hoy, rango):
         df.loc[i,"Status"] = ("Closed")
```

Y esto solucionara tu problema :)